# I can not call the variable

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

```
document.getElementById("quilltext").value = '[{"insert":"12312312312312312312312312\n"}]';

var x = document.getElementById("quilltext").value;

quill.setContents(x);
```

doesn't work, but

```
quill.setContents([{"insert":"12312312312312312312312312\n"}]);
```

works fine.

Comment: Post the HTML too so that the problem is reproducible. (What is `quill`?)

Comment: check the browser developer tools console for errors

Comment: quill rich text editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the question, if `setContents()` with array input works then you can try converting the string value with `JSON.parse()`:

```
quill.setContents(JSON.parse(x));
```

Comment: Please explain your answer!